# Problems with creating variables within threads and passing pointers

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

I am currently learning about good and bad practices concerning multi-threading. To my understanding, it is bad practice to create a local variable within a thread (t1) and pass a pointer to it to another thread (t2). I know that t1's stack is dynamic and so t2 may not always be accessing the correct data. However, is it possible that if t2 writes to this pointer, that t2 could execute the wrong code? Since this modification is taking place in t1's stack, it can only really affect t1 right? Unless, of course, t2 depends on t1 later on in execution. What are some ways I can think about this problem? Or anyone have any good resources about how per-thread stacks work?

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is that it depends.  You're perfectly entitled to offer your own stack to another thread, but you better make damn sure that you synchronise the threads to prevent race conditions, including preventing the value from going out of scope until the other thread is done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack for a thread is just an area of memory that has been reserved for that thread. It's simply a "conventional" thing though. There's no enforcement of that separation and the area of memory is in fact shared by *all* threads.

So, as @paddy commented, you're perfectly free to pass the address of a local variable created by thread A to thread B. However, you must *not* return from the creating function in thread A. Otherwise, that stack memory will (almost certainly) be re-used by whatever thread A does next. (It's a good idea to make sure you understand how the stack is used by your language / compiler.)

Apart from that, synchronization of the value in that variable is exactly the same as for any other variable shared among threads.

Technically you're correct that thread B simply writing to a variable on thread A's stack cannot directly perturb anything that thread B is doing. However, if thread A *did* return from the function that created the variable, then thread B's writing to it is essentially firing a torpedo into a "random" location in thread A's execution path. The memory might now be holding some other variable in some other function, or it could now be holding the return address of some function on thread A's stack.

So since the corruption of thread A leads to undefined behavior in thread A's execution path, it is extremely likely to eventually lead to undefined behavior / corruption in thread B's execution path as well (and any other threads).

Just think through the potential effects:

- If you were to change the least significant byte(s) of a return
  address, you're going to cause thread A to return to what may well be
  a valid region of code, but *not* the code immediately following the
  function call that thread A was executing before the write.
- If you end up changing the more significant bytes of the return address,
  thread A is likely to return to a non-executable portion of its
  virtual address space (likely leading to an exception and error exit which will take down all threads).
- If you end up changing a variable value (or a saved register value), well, who knows what that will do? It
  depends totally on the function that gets corrupted and what it was
  using that memory location for. You could be changing an array index to an
  out-of-bounds value, or a file descriptor to refer to a
  different open file, or a floating point value to a NaN value. Or corrupting a memory pool pointer inside a library routine called by thread A. *Or* changing a pointer value so that it now points back into thread B's stack.

Comment: Thank you! This explanation was really illuminating, and the example of thread A's stack holding a return address at that location was a powerful example.